# How to get ArrayList return from a asmx webmethod

Tags: c#, .net

I have a ASMX webservice and have a method which is returning an ArrayList..its working fine but I dont know how to get the Array items from the client code. here is the asmx method

```
[WebMethod]
public ReturnParcel[] getConStrings(string dbType)
{
   var OdbName = GetSetting(document, "Odbname");
   var OuserName = GetSetting(document, "Ousername");
   var Opassword = GetSetting(document, "Opassword");
   if (dbType == "Oracle")
   {
      return new ReturnParcel[] {new ReturnParcel { DBName = OdbName, UserID = OuserName, Password = Opassword },};
   }
   else
   {
      return new ReturnParcel[] {new ReturnParcel { DBName = SdbName, UserID = SuserName, Password = Spassword },};
   }
}

public class ReturnParcel
{
   public string DBName { get; set; }
   public string UserID { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
 WebServiceProxy.OraSPDataXchange objServiceClient = new WebServiceProxy.OraSPDataXchange();
 objServiceClient.Url = "http://portal.mydomain.local/_layouts/SPCustomWS/OraSPDataXchange.asmx";

 objServiceClient.getConStrings("Oracle");
```

check the last line of client code..there i need to get that returned values..so need to know how to get it here..

Comment: Your method seems to return Array of ReturnParcel items, not ArrayList. In client part you are already getting those values, but just ignoring the return values. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why not do this: ReturnParcel[] items = objServiceClient.getConStrings("Oracle"); ?

Comment: Are you trying to cast the returned items to an `ArrayList`?

Comment: The collection type in the client proxy does not need to be the same type as the server side collection type. The type is configured in the proxy generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume

```
var receivedConnectionStrings = objServiceClient.getConStrings("Oracle");
```

would put the result in the `receivedConnectionStrings` variable.

Comment: Albin you got it right :) do you think this will give me the values?

string adbname = receivedConnectionStrings[0].DBName.ToString();
                string auserid = receivedConnectionStrings[1].Password.ToString();